# how can display different text when hover over a different image using only CSS and HTML?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have made a image and text hovering effect.I have four images and four paragraphs for each image.When hover on any image the specific paragraph for that image should be displayed in the place of the previous paragraph using only HTML and CSS. PLEASE READ THE FOLLOWING:- The design should be in a way that the discovery paragraph should be active if not hovered over any other text.The below code is what i have used to proceed but it is not working:-

Here is the Html code:-

```
        <div class="image-slide">
        <a href="#discovery"><img src="discovery.jpg" alt="discovery"></a>
        <a href="#recommendation"><img src="recommendation.jpg" alt="recommend"></a>
        <a href="#implementaion"><img src="implementaion.jpg" alt="implementation"></a>
        <a href="#review"><img src="review.jpg" alt="review"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="discovery" class="paragraph-slide">
        <h3>Discovery</h3>
        <p>This meeting is held about one week after the FIT Meeting and normally runs about two hours. This is where all the pertinent financial data is gathered and reviewed. We take a very comprehensive approach,and therefore need  every itty bitty detail to formulate the right financial plan to work towards your needs and goals.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="recommendation" class="paragraph-slide">
        <h3>Recommendation</h3>
        <p>This meeting is held about one week after the FIT Meeting and normally runs about two hours. This is where all the pertinent financial data is gathered and reviewed. We take a very comprehensive approach,and therefore need  every itty bitty detail to formulate the right financial plan to work towards your needs and goals.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="implementaion" class="paragraph-slide">
        <h3>Implementaion</h3>
        <p>This meeting is held about one week after the FIT Meeting and normally runs about two hours. This is where all the pertinent financial data is gathered and reviewed. We take a very comprehensive approach,and therefore need  every itty bitty detail to formulate the right financial plan to work towards your needs and goals.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="review" class="paragraph-slide">
        <h3>Review</h3>
        <p>This meeting is held about one week after the FIT Meeting and normally runs about two hours. This is where all the pertinent financial data is gathered and reviewed. We take a very comprehensive approach,and therefore need  every itty bitty detail to formulate the right financial plan to work towards your needs and goals.</p>
    </div>
```

Here is the css code:-

```
.image-slide{
margin: 50px 0px 30px 50px;
}

.company-process h3{
    font-family: 'Cinzel-Regular';
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #1a1a1a;
    text-align: center;
    margin:50px 0 5px 0;
}

.company-process img{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.company-process .paragraph-slide p{
    font-family: 'Raleway-Regular';
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #666666;
    margin:20px 50px 20px 50px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit tricky, but I somehow got the idea of what's you are looking for. I just set different html tags but I think my code is somehow understandable. But anyways, if you have clarifications, please do ask :)

So, here's a summary of what I've done:

First step in the HTML code, I wrapped all the images (figure tag) in div tag (container class). And I reversed the order of images.

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <figure>
      <span>image 4 - review</span>
      <figcaption>This is review</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
       <span>image 3 - implementation</span>
      <figcaption>This is implementation</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
       <span>image 2 - recommendation</span>
      <figcaption>This is recommendation</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
       <span>image 1 - discovery</span>
      <figcaption>This is discovery</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why the reversal though? Let's go with the second step below.

Second will be the CSS part. I reversed the order of the images of having the idea that the caption of the last image should be shown without hovering but displayed none if its siblings is hovered. But I give "float: right" first the images (figure tags) so that it gives the right order as an output.

```css
figure {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

And by default, all the captions is "display: none" but the caption of the last image (which is the image 1 in the order of my HTMl code) is "display: block".

```css
figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

figure:last-child figcaption {
  display: block;
}
```

Then, whenever the captions of the images is hovered except the last image, I give "display: block".

```css
figure:not(last-child):hover figcaption {
  display: block;
}
```

And to "display: none" the caption of the last image (the image 1 in the order of my HTMl code), you have to use the "~" (figure:not(last-child):hover ~ figure:last-child figcaption) css selector to achieve this.

```css
figure:not(last-child):hover ~ figure:last-child figcaption {
  display: none;
}
```

The general idea of "~" css selector is it points to all the preceding elements.

Here's the full code:

```css
.container {
  float: left;
}

figure {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin: 5px;
}

figure span {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

figure:last-child figcaption {
  display: block;
}

figure:not(last-child):hover figcaption {
  display: block;
}

figure:not(last-child):hover ~ figure:last-child figcaption {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <figure>
      <span>image 4 - review</span>
      <figcaption>This is review</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
       <span>image 3 - implementation</span>
      <figcaption>This is implementation</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
       <span>image 2 - recommendation</span>
      <figcaption>This is recommendation</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
       <span>image 1 - discovery</span>
      <figcaption>This is discovery</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A good answer should explain what it does, not just rely on the  code. Either add some comments to your code or add a brief explanation of what you've done. Having to reverse the order of the html to accommodate `float:right` may not be obvious to the inexperienced. You should also explain why you had to reverse the order. Otherwise you've nailed it.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm really not good at explaining. I find it hard to explain sometimes on what's on my mind. But anyways, thank you and I edited my answer. I wish somehow it's clear.

Comment: Edit helped a lot. Explaining something to others can be hard, but it is one of those things that tends to get better with practice. The more you answer here, the better you will get at it.

Comment: Well said. Thank you @JonP . I'm new to stackoverflow though, but I got to practice. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You need to write few line Javascript, check below code

```js
$('.image-slide a').hover(function() {
  $('.paragraph-slide').hide();
  var target = $(this).attr('href');
  $(target).show();
});
```

```css
.image-slide {
  margin: 50px 0px 30px 50px;
}

.company-process h3 {
  font-family: "Cinzel-Regular";
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #1a1a1a;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px 0 5px 0;
}

.company-process img {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.company-process .paragraph-slide p {
  font-family: "Raleway-Regular";
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #666666;
  margin: 20px 50px 20px 50px;
  padding: 0;
}

.paragraph-slide {
  display: none;
}

.paragraph-slide.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-slide">
  <a href="#discovery"><img src="discovery.jpg" alt="discovery"></a>
  <a href="#recommendation"><img src="recommendation.jpg" alt="recommend"></a>
  <a href="#implementaion"><img src="implementaion.jpg" alt="implementation"></a>
  <a href="#review"><img src="review.jpg" alt="review"></a>
</div>
<div id="discovery" class="paragraph-slide active">
  <h3>Discovery</h3>
  <p>This meeting is held about one week after the FIT Meeting and normally runs about two hours. This is where all the pertinent financial data is gathered and reviewed. We take a very comprehensive approach,and therefore need every itty bitty detail to
    formulate the right financial plan to work towards your needs and goals.</p>
</div>
<div id="recommendation" class="paragraph-slide">
  <h3>Recommendation</h3>
  <p>This meeting is held about one week after the FIT Meeting and normally runs about two hours. This is where all the pertinent financial data is gathered and reviewed. We take a very comprehensive approach,and therefore need every itty bitty detail to
    formulate the right financial plan to work towards your needs and goals.</p>
</div>

<div id="implementaion" class="paragraph-slide">
  <h3>Implementaion</h3>
  <p>This meeting is held about one week after the FIT Meeting and normally runs about two hours. This is where all the pertinent financial data is gathered and reviewed. We take a very comprehensive approach,and therefore need every itty bitty detail to
    formulate the right financial plan to work towards your needs and goals.</p>
</div>
<div id="review" class="paragraph-slide">
  <h3>Review</h3>
  <p>This meeting is held about one week after the FIT Meeting and normally runs about two hours. This is where all the pertinent financial data is gathered and reviewed. We take a very comprehensive approach,and therefore need every itty bitty detail to
    formulate the right financial plan to work towards your needs and goals.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: i cannot use javascript,i can only use bootstrap,custom css and html

Answer (score 0):

Use img's `title` attribute `<img src="...." alt="this will show if the image is not loaded" title="this will show on hover"/>`

Comment: can you be more specific ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following.

Move the text into the anchor tag. Set a panel with to position the text relatively in. Hide the text be default an when the anchor is hovered show the text.

```css
.pane {position:relative;}
.pane .image-slide img {height:100px;}
.pane a {float:left;}
.pane .paragraph-slide
{
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
  top: 150px;
  left: 0;
}

.pane a:hover .paragraph-slide {
  display:block;
}


.image-slide {
  margin: 50px 0px 30px 50px;
}

.company-process h3 {
  font-family: 'Cinzel-Regular';
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #1a1a1a;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px 0 5px 0;
}

.company-process img {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.company-process .paragraph-slide p {
  font-family: 'Raleway-Regular';
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #666666;
  margin: 20px 50px 20px 50px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="pane">
  <div class="image-slide">
    <a href="#discovery"><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/300" alt="discovery">
      <div id="discovery" class="paragraph-slide">
        <h3>Discovery</h3>
        <p>This meeting is held about one week after the FIT Meeting and normally runs about two hours. This is where all the pertinent financial data is gathered and reviewed. We take a very comprehensive approach,and therefore need every itty bitty detail
          to formulate the right financial plan to work towards your needs and goals.</p>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#recommendation"><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/300/300" alt="recommend">
      <div id="recommendation" class="paragraph-slide">
        <h3>Recommendation</h3>
        <p>This meeting is held about one week after the FIT Meeting and normally runs about two hours. This is where all the pertinent financial data is gathered and reviewed. We take a very comprehensive approach,and therefore need every itty bitty detail
          to formulate the right financial plan to work towards your needs and goals.</p>
      </div>

    </a>
    <a href="#implementaion"><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/400/300" alt="implementation">
      <div id="implementaion" class="paragraph-slide">
        <h3>Implementaion</h3>
        <p>This meeting is held about one week after the FIT Meeting and normally runs about two hours. This is where all the pertinent financial data is gathered and reviewed. We take a very comprehensive approach,and therefore need every itty bitty detail
          to formulate the right financial plan to work towards your needs and goals.</p>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#review"><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/300" alt="review">
      <div id="review" class="paragraph-slide">
        <h3>Review</h3>
        <p>This meeting is held about one week after the FIT Meeting and normally runs about two hours. This is where all the pertinent financial data is gathered and reviewed. We take a very comprehensive approach,and therefore need every itty bitty detail
          to formulate the right financial plan to work towards your needs and goals.</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the discovery should always be active.As i remove the cursor the text also goes away,one of text which is discovery should always be active.How do i achieve that?

Comment: The nature of pure CSS hover effects is that they revert back to the default state/style when the cursor leaves the hover area. You'll need JS to toggle an active state class to keep the text open when the cursor leaves the image... can you not insert script inline with the HTML?

Comment: @kaunishroy, you can't with pure HTML/CSS and hover. You can do it on click by several methods or with javascript.

Comment: Can we do it with bootstrap because i have done a active link and onClick different paragraph display with bootstrap

Comment: Bootstrap 4 uses javascript (and jQuery) so I can't really see a vaild reason **not** to use javascript.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58832682/4665) achieves what you are looking for but involves some slightly awkward re-ordering of content.